# MongoDB replication not working

Tags: mongodb, replication

I am exploring the replication functionality in MongoDB, just wanted to clarify a simple scenario.

I have a java program which is inserting values in the db constantly in a three instance replica set, now if i shutdown the primary the java program just throws an ioexception and exits. Shouldn't it continue inserting in after the election when a new primary is selected whereas i can see using mongo shell that a new primary is selected and everything is fine.

```
May 06, 2016 10:13:26 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:10}] to akhurraml2:27017 because there was a socket exception raised on another connection from this pool.
May 06, 2016 10:13:26 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server akhurraml2:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:142)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more

May 06, 2016 10:13:27 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:6}] to akhurraml2:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:46)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:96)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:228)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:515)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:306)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:297)
    at com.nextcontrols.App.main(App.java:33)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet where you are setting up your MongoClient DB option ? Basically the part where you are defining the server instances.

Comment: MongoClient client = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(
                new ServerAddress("AKhurramL2", 27017),
                new ServerAddress("AKhurramL2", 27018),
                new ServerAddress("AKhurramL2", 27019)));

        MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("test");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("recharge");
        collection.drop();
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
          Document doc = new   Document("reference",""+i).append("owner", "a"+i);
          collection.insertOne(doc);
 Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Arbiters are nodes that do not keep a copy of the data. However, arbiters play a role in the elections that select a primary if the current primary is unavailable. Are you sure the two other nodes are not arbiters?

Comment: I am pretty sure they are regular nodes as using mongo shell i can see a new primary being selected and if i connect to all the nodes separately i can see them having data after doing rs.slaveOk(). I am starting all the nodes using same command e.g.   mongod --replSet m101 --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27017

Answer (score 0):

Adding following code handles the exceptions. It keeps waiting till the failover is happening and then retries inserts:

```
try{
     collection.insertOne(doc);

     }catch (Exception e){

        System.out.println(e);
   }
```